# jquery/ajax script not working under bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working bootstrap template (an as of yet unmodified dashboard).

I have a separate html file that uses AJAX/jQuery to grab data from a PHP page in a system health monitoring capacity.  The html/PHP pair work fine.

When I try to incorporate the health monitoring portion to the working boot strap page nothing is displayed.

here is the html/ajax/jquery that works fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#health_monitor').load('health.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="health_monitor"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I add the head portion to the head of bootstrap, and have tried putting the
     
portion in many different places within the body of the bootstrap template, and it doesnt show anything (no error, nor a 1, or a 0)

any suggestions?

Comment: Why jquery 1.3? just don't include jQuery for this script, bootstrap has it's own version of jQuery that you can use for this.

Comment: Your script is firing against the `#health_monitor` element before it has properly resolved in the DOM. Put your script inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... });` and it should work, unless you have a conflict with the version of jQuery included with bootstrap (do not include multiple versions of jQuery).

Comment: ok, I removed the call for jQuery 1.3, and put the script within the function above.  so it looks like this:    

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
<script type="text/javascript">
  
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(
 function ()
 {
 $('#health_monitor').load('health.php').fadeIn("fast");
 }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
 
</script>
});`

Comment: I ran the debug console and found a cross site problem.  added the following and